# How to Increment the File name of output file

Tags: java, file-io

I have already increment the filename but the problem is that i need to do it without using file exist method because my file Output was creating in separate Folder so starts by 1 again.

```
      int increase=1; //Use for Increment the file name
             String name =String.valueOf(increase);
       String CSVFile = "C:\\Vstore\\OurHome\\sales\\CUST0780030";
       File f = new File(CSVFile+dateFormat.format(date)+name+".CSV");
       while(f.exists()){
           increase++;
           name =String.valueOf(increase);
           f= new File(CSVFile+dateFormat.format(date)+name+".CSV");
       }
       CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(f.getAbsoluteFile()),
               '|',
               CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
               CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
               "\r\n");
```

Comment: _"i need to do it without using file exist method"_ what do you mean by this? Only use it for some folders and not for the others?

Comment: well sir my output will be created in separate Folder so file.exists is not working is there any other way to keep incrementing  the file name without checking if the file.exists

Comment: is there any other way to increment my file name.